# AsyncTask - onPostExecute is never called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using an asyncTask in my app, but it's not calling the onPostExecute method. I read it dozen of times and couldn't find an error.

It flows like this:

1. MainActivity
2. --> user clicks on button
3. -->calls a class
4. -->call another class with a method that show some messages and then executes the AsyncTask.

This is the full class and the AsyncTask:

```
package com.vdlow.socialnotification.twitter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.vdlow.socialnotification.R;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import twitter4j.IDs;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TwitterUtils {
    static long userID;
    static Context c;
    static Boolean retornoSend;

    public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        try {
            twitter.getAccountSettings();
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs,String msg, Context cs) throws Exception {
        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
        String values[] = {token, secret, msg};
        TwitterUtils tu = new TwitterUtils();
        TweetSender ts = tu.new TweetSender();
        ts.execute(values);
        Log.i("retornoSend", retornoSend.toString());
        if(retornoSend){
            Toast.makeText(cs, cs.getString(R.string.tweet_sent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(cs, cs.getString(R.string.fail_sending), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }   

    public static ArrayList<String> getUserId(final SharedPreferences prefs) throws Exception{
        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        try {
            userID = twitter.getId();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("Error! Method: getUserId() Class: TwitterUtils", e.toString());
        } 
        Log.i("USERID", String.valueOf(userID));
        ArrayList<String> following = new ArrayList<String>();
        long lCursor = -1;
        try{
            userID = twitter.getId();
            IDs friendsIDs = twitter.getFriendsIDs(userID, lCursor); 
            do
            {
                for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs())
                {
                    following.add("@"+twitter.showUser(i).getScreenName());
                }
            }while(friendsIDs.hasNext());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Exception! Class TwitterUtils Method: getFriendsName()", e.toString()+"\n User ID "+String.valueOf(userID));
        }
        return following;

    }

    private class TweetSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... msg) {
            Looper.prepare();
            String token = msg[0];
            String secret = msg[1];

            AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
            try {
                twitter.updateStatus(msg[2]);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.e("Error sending tweet Class TwitterUtils Method sendTweet() AsyncTask TweetSender", e.toString());
                return false;
            }           

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            Log.i("Post execute", "Runned");
            retornoSend = result;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Does the doInBackground complete? What happens if you put a log before return true? My guess is that one of the twitter calls is blocking

Comment: Is `TweetSender` a nested class of `TwitterUtils`? If so, show us `TwitterUtils`...

Comment: I put a log before true and it logged, so, it's completing the execution. Also, the tweet is being sent, so it's another sign that the doInBackGround is working. I'll update the post with the TwitterUtils class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `doInBackground` is either never completing, or you cancel the request at some point:

from the developer docs (see bold text below): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not
>   be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has
>   not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the
>   task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter
>   determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
>
> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. **Calling
>   this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked.**
>   After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.